# Does William Wallace's face paint in Braveheart have a special meaning?

Tags: braveheart

The iconic picture of William Wallace with face painted for battle in the movie [*Braveheart* (1995)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112573/):

[image]

Does this design have any special meaning?  There are others with face paint, and some resemble symbols:

[image]

I've always wondered whether these had special meaning, but most specifically the one on Wallace's face.

Comment: Having just looked at 18 ancient language alphabets and sets of runic symbols, I am unable to find anything resembling the two designs in the photos you include in your question - I paid particular heed to the Pictish runes and alphabet, even looking at their art (in the stone slabs).

Comment: @GhotiandChips - not taking anything away from the 2 answers already here, this answer is probably more on-point to what I asked.

Comment: That's Jeor Mormont [James Cosmo](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0181920/) or I'm a monkey's uncle. *(DNA tests required for simian proof ;)*

Comment: @Tetsujin Actors sometimes play more than one role during their lifetime. Crazy, right? It's just pure insanity.

Comment: Next you'll be trying to tell me Spock was in Mission Impossible... I'll not have it, I tell ya ;)

Answer (score 16):

Short answer: No.

One of the most historically inaccurate movies of all time.
These were simply decorative for the movie.  Most of the imagery can be taken with huge grains of salt.

Check out this fantastic breakdown by the History Buffs youtube guy:

Comment: I read somewhere that Wallace's face was *supposed* to have St. Andrew's Cross but that Gibson decided to change it.  Not knowing much, if anything, about Scotland, I figured maybe he changed it to something else still relevant to Scotland.

Comment: Only the color blue was relevant.  The Picts had this tradition but it was stopped long before the time of Wallace.

Comment: @BlueGI That may well be worth including in your answer (that it's inspired by the blue "tattoos" found on the Pictish) - even if it is historically inaccurate for many reasons, it would at least serve as an answer for what the reason was for using this (sadly) iconic blue face paint.

Comment: @GhotiandChips - Keep in mind my question was specifically about the design, not the color or even paint.  I was curious if the *design* meant anything to the Scottish (was it part of a well-known Coat of Arms, for instance), although the info about the paint was interesting to know.  In fact, considering how St. Andrew's Cross was more of an "X" than a traditional Christian cross, I find the design on the old man's face to be curious as well (although it's clearly a cross).

Comment: The question wasn’t whether or not the paint was historically accurate; it was whether or not there was any meaning behind the particular design painted on Gibson’s face. The design may well have been chosen for symbolic reasons *unrelated* to history; the director, costume designer, or Gibson himself might have chosen it for a particular reason. Whether or not they did (and, if they did, what that reason was) is in my mind necessary to fully answer this question. Even if they wrongly believed they were accurately depicting the historical practice of woad, they picked that design—why?

Comment: "One of the most historically inaccurate movies of all time." So you're telling me that the battle cry of an army fighting for rule by a local feudal Earl rather than a Norman feudal king in a succession dispute wasn't "**Freedom!**" ? Mind, blown.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Actually it was Burwell who chose a different design, not Gibson.

Comment: @KRyan But BlueGl is saying "No, there is no meaning behind the design", and then consoling the reader (who might be wondering why on Earth, then, they'd include it in the movie) by reminding the reader of how inaccurate the movie is, and therefore giving satisfying plausibility that it is a made-up design that holds no "special" meaning.

Comment: @GhotiandChips You are correct, there is a statement at the outset asserting that the answer is No. That assertion is not at all backed up—the rest of the answer addresses solely the historical inaccuracy of the woad, not the intended symbolism, if any, of the design chosen.

Comment: @KRyan True - but addressing the movie's laundry lists of inaccuracies seems to be resonating with people as evidence that there is satisfying plausibility that they just made up these symbols and that they do not hold special meaning, hence the upvotes. I'm not defending the answer or saying it has compelling reasoning to back its claims, merely laying things out the way I interpret them.

Comment: Found a number of references crediting Lois Burwell for the face-painting designs, as noted above, with no evidence there was any particular meaning to the designs other than being visually impressive on camera.

Answer (score 8):

Here is also a list of Errors in Braveheart, but the painted blue faces are not entirely inaccurate, it's just it was not used for battle and out of practice by the time of Wallace, as the idea of it may stem Pict Tradition.

> Error #4: The Scots didn’t paint their faces for battle
>
> At least they no longer did by the time of Wallace. What Gibson was
>   obviously alluding to is the Scottish Picts’ tradition of painting
>   their faces blue to scare off those pansies, the Romans, from their
>   lands. Of course, Emperor Adrian would have nothing of it and built a
>   wall to keep those evil buggers from sacking the rest of Britain while
>   the sandal-folk still ruled the scene.
>
> The blue face-paint is so iconic, though, you couldn’t imagine
>   BraveHeart without it. These days of course the tradition is to paint
>   the flag of Scotland (a white X across with blue sides) for sporting
>   events.

https://thehande.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/braveheart-the-10-historical-inaccuracies-you-need-to-know-before-watching-the-movie/

> Q: Why do they wear blue or blue and white makeup?
>
> If you didn’t know, these are the Scottish colors. You can see them on
>   Scotland’s flag.
>
> Q:  What is that paint?
>
> It’s called woad. It’s a plant and the blue dye is produced from the
>   leaves.
>
> Q: Did Braveheart really wear that paint into battle?
>
> Probably not. Most historians think the paint was an earlier
>   phenomenon (Wikipedia has a lengthy section on historical inaccuracies
>   in the film). We also like the nit-picking produced on this blog’s
>   Braveheart tag.

https://triviahappy.com/articles/5-questions-about-scottish-face-makeup-as-seen-in-braveheart

History of Picts
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picts

Comment: It was the Emperor *Hadrian* who built the wall  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadrian%27s_Wall

Comment: The question wasn’t whether or not the paint was historically accurate; it was whether or not there was any meaning behind the particular design painted on Gibson’s face. The design may well have been chosen for symbolic reasons unrelated to history; the director, costume designer, or Gibson himself might have chosen it for a particular reason. Whether or not they did (and, if they did, what that reason was) is in my mind necessary to fully answer this question. Even if they wrongly believed they were accurately depicting the historical practice of woad, they picked that design—why?

Comment: But by replaying with an answer that relates to how it was or wasn't accurate, I also included links  (Wikipedia Pict) and/or other people's answers on how it was significant, as the paint may come from Pict culture, @KRyan Pict Culture being apart of Celtic culture, and the color blue itself is a color of Scotland, but I could not find direct significance on the choice of the specific design in the film--this information was as close as I could get, as Pict culture is still a culture being studied and there are different schools of thought relating to certain things.

Comment: Note: Adrian is another form of the name Hadrian - if you go to the Wikipedia page of the name [Adrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrian) you see information about Hadrian and a bust of Hadrian pictured, and that the name originates from the region formerly known as [Adria or Hadria.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atri,_Abruzzo)

Answer (score 0):

To the gentleman who had trouble finding Celtic symbology among the runes, perhaps that is because runes are Nordic, not Celtic. The Celts had the Ogham Alphabet that was likely used for divination as well as an alphabet and a nemonic device for students, but the woad paint was more likely to reflect the natural world's shapes and images. Braveheart is indeed an inaccurate depiction of the Celts. The two pictures above show woad painted on in straight lines dividing a face in two, and in the form of a cross. The non-Christianized, non-Romanized Celts in any age were not a linear people, and even when the church later forced their cross imagery on them, they added a circle to the cross to represent the old culture. Their symbology came from nature: circles, spirals, trees, the salmon. Not straight lines, and not binary divisions of the face. This is one of thousands of examples of our current Romanized Christian cosmology trying to depict an ancient, animist, egalitarian, ecocentric, non-binary culture and failing miserably.